# Retrieve the value of a nested object that has a changing name with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, aws-lambda

I am having trouble trying to get a value from a list of objects in a Woocommerce webhook. Woocommerce inputs the order number of the selected dropdown (ie.Royal Mail is 5th in the dropdown, USPS is 3rd) so I need to be able to access this when it is any value.

```
var labelchoice = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].label; // SUCCESS This returns "Custom"
var labelchoice1 = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[0].value.5.value; // FAILED with "Unexpected Number"
var labelchoice2 = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value.value.5.value; // FAILED with "Unexpected Number"
var labelchoice3 = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[0].value[0].5.value; // FAILED with "Unexpected Number"
var labelchoice4 = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[0].value[0].5[0].value; // FAILED with "Unexpected Number"
```

The number "5" that is referenced is the number of the dropdown option (there are 8 options eg. USPS, Airmail etc) on a product page. The problem here is I don't know what the number is going to be selected (the dropdown the customer chooses) so that "5" object needs to be perhaps referenced as a wildcard as it could be any number from 1-8.

Can anyone help me grab that nested "label" value? - shown in the example as "Royal Mail"

```
"meta_data": [
    {
    "id": 166,
    "key": "Dropdown options",
    "value": "Custom"
    },
    {
    "id": 167,
    "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
    "value": [
        {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "select-1549626172813",
        "label": "Custom",
        "value": {
            "5": {
            "i": 5,
            "value": "UK-RM",
            "label": "Royal Mail"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the property name (`5`) is not known, it can be queried:

```js
var labelchoiceX = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[
  Object.keys(event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value)[0]
].label;
```

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks so much for persevering with that, I was totally stuck! Ticked :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index as a string variable

```js
const index = '5' // or any other value from the select dropdown
const labelchoice = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[index].label
```

Here's in action: https://codepen.io/herodrigues/pen/RvYqeL

Comment: Thanks Hero, the problem is I do not know what the "index" is going to be. So for example if you change the "5" value to "6" and run that pen nothing gets returned.

Comment: It's because there's no index 6 in the object. I was supposing you'd have all the values in your object. 
You need to set the values of the select dropdown options as numbers {1,2,3...}. Then get the value of the selected option and assign it to the index variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are after the `[]` property access syntax.

```js
const m = new Map();
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  m.set(i,  
    event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value[String(i)].value /* or .label? */);
}
```

Comment: This answer looks a bit more promising. How can I assign this for loop to a variable, like I previously did ```var labelchoice = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].label;```

Comment: Well, do you only need to retrieve the nested value for a known index? Or for all indices (in which case the variable will be a map)

Comment: Edited my answer to store the results in a map, but yeah @herodrigues's answer is also correct and it's not clear what you're after exactly

Comment: Sorry if its unclear, just trying to grab the value of that nested value right at the bottom. Currently showing as "Royal Mail" and then assign it to a variable. ```"5": {
            "i": 5``` will always change whereas the other objects will have static names.

Comment: I see. Posted another answer then (above)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I think this is the correct order:

var labelchoice = event.line_items[0].meta_data[1].value[0].value.5.label;

Comment: You cannot access keys as numbers without the `[]` access syntax. Otherwise, you'll get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`